A collection of Russian Fairy Tales, much more than 60 years old
This is a very, very old memory. I got it as a present when I was still in elementary school (or, maybe, it was a present of graduation, at its very end) : a beautiful illustrated hardcover book of Russian Fairy Tales, in French translation, of course. I got it in 1962 at the latest. This particular book was new, but it need not have been the first French edition, and the Russian original was certainly somewhat older. The Russian society, as described in the book, was of course much older, still feudal, but this need not be a precise indication of the year when these traditional tales were collected, edited and first printed.
There were several stories. I don't remember just how many. About half a dozen, I think. And I have few precise memories.
One is about a fabulous animal that left two trails behind him, one of gold powder, the other one of black powder. But when two (or more) children found such a double trail, and tried to pick up the gold powder, it turned black. Then came a woman. (Later it appears that the woman was none other than the fabulous animal, in human form). She  picked up a bit of both powders, mixed them and produced pebbles of mixed black and gold. She gave such a pebble to each child, telling them that the fate of the pebble would depend on their future behaviour. Of course only one of the two (or more) children obtained gold, all the others got only black rock.
Another memory of that collection, maybe the beginning of this tale, more probably in a different tale. Just a character: he was a nasty foreman, devoted to his master, cruel to the peasants. I forgot his first name, say XXX, but his full nickname was "XXX Dépêchez", that is "XXX Hurry up", because he was always hurrying the peasants to work harder and faster.
Sorry I don't remember anything else.

I did a search for "Russian Fairy Tales" adv. search 1800-1962 on Abe Books.
There wasn't a place to specify a language. But there was a "search within results" where you could type French. (Didn't help me, but who knows?) https://www.abebooks.com/servlet/SearchResults?bi=0&bx=off&cm_sp=SearchF-_-AdvsResult&ds=20&kn=russian%20fairy%20tales&pt=book%2Cms&recentlyadded=all&rollup=on&sortby=20&sts=t&xdesc=off&xpod=off&yrh=1962&yrl=1800

@OccamShave Well, too many choices without the "search within results" and the latter did not help me, either...

Do remember the pictures? Style, colorscheme? Was it illustrated inside too? i.e.: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivan_Bilibin

@Allerleirauh It was illustrated inside too. But I don't remember a "style" or a "colorscheme". It was for children or YA. Nothing as elaborated as van Bilibin

Did the pictures in my link ring any bell?

@Allerleirauh As far as topics are concerned, vaguely. Well, russian. Style, intricacy, definitely not. When I wrote "beautiful illustrated book", I am thinking as the 10 years old child, which I was when I got it. Not as a connoisseur.

@Allerleirauh  I think it was a gift from my elementary school for the end of my final year. They would not give books illustrated by artists like van Bilibin to schoolchildren !

I asked, because I had (and have) a book with this artists pictures from my childhood too. The pictures impressed me long lasting :) and I know they were used in a wide range of books with russian tales.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
